# Testing to update a non-updatable column in Spring Boot Application, the value in database is not changed but the return value from method is changed

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am writing a Spring Boot Application on creating and managing personal note. I have a Note entity class which have createdDate attribute with annotations like this
`

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@NotBlank
@Size(max=30)
private String title;

private String content;

@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Date createdDate;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date updatedDate;
```

`

I wrote a NoteService method to update the note
`

```
@Override
public Note updateNote(Note note) {
    return noteRepository.save(note);
}
```

`

I wrote an updateNote method in NoteController to call.
`

```
@@PutMapping("/notes/{note_id}")
public NoteDTO updateNote(@RequestBody Note note, @PathVariable Long note_id) throws IOException {
    note.setId(note_id);
    Note updatedNote = noteService.updateNote(note);
    NoteDTO noteDTO = modelMapper.map(updatedNote, NoteDTO.class);
    return noteDTO;
}
```

`

I committed a API test with postmna to check if I send a PUT request with provided createdDate will it update the createdDate column.

After send request, I received response with createdDate updated but when I check the database it still be the same
[Postman API test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtYxZ.png)

When I check database record
[Database record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMpX8.png)

I tried to change controller method code. After updating the note using noteService.updateNote(note) I call the method Note updatedNote =  noteService.getNoteById(note_id) but the problem still be same